# Messaging between application and SSRS report

Tags: angularjs, reporting-services

I have an Angular application where I have implemented SSRS reports. I am showing a report by navigating to a state defined like this:

```
.state('viewreport', {
                url: '/viewreport',
                templateUrl: 'SSRSReportTemplate.html',
                controller: 'SSRSReportTemplateController',
        }
```

The template looks like this:

```
<iframe id="reportArea" ng-src="{{iframeSrc}}"
    style="border:none;width:100%;background-color:white;padding-top:5px;">
</iframe>
```

In order to load a report I am navigating to the above state:

```
$state.go('viewreport');
```

In the state controller I am defining iframeSrc:

```
$scope.iframeSrc = 'report URL';
```

After that report starts loading into template's iframe.
Everything works without any problem.

Here is what I am trying to do. I have managed adding a button to the report's toolbar. I want to send a message from that button to the main application to execute some code. I have tried something like this from a click of the new button:

```
 window.postMessage('message', '*');
```

and in the main application:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
     alert(1);
}, false);
```

Nothing was happening.
I also tried:

```
window.postMessage('message', 'main app URL');
```

then I was getting cors error.

After that I thought I could have used localStorage. But when I check it at a break point in the new button's click it does not match the one I have in the main application.

At this point I am stuck. Any idea of how to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: How did you add the button to the toolbar? If the report is loaded from another domain outside of your app you may have to give permissions to your iframe to fully load everything.

Comment: https://insomniacgeek.com/2012/02/26/how-to-add-a-clear-button-to-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs/

Comment: That frame will come back with content that should have an element named oReport, but that is inside your iframe. Are you sure your events are hooked up the way you think they are. That article suggests a way to bind events within a .aspx page containing  a ReportViewer control. That is somewhat different than loading the content in the manner you have posted above.

Comment: Well, I am not really sure. What I understand is that PostMessage from the Clear button is not reaching my environment. As well as LocalStorage of the report is not what LocalStorage of my application is. Besides these two approaches I dont have any other idea.